# How to build a gas giant?

Tags: planets, science-fiction, atmosphere

In this universe, gravity wells are needed to enter and exit FTL, many cheap spacecraft are not armored enough to go near a star so gas giants are the next best option.

One particular solar system has only one, very large, gas giant as well as several rocky planets, one of which is habitable and also many asteroids, moons, and dwarf planets. There is a limit to how often ships can use the same well for travel so with only one well to use this significantly limits the trade potential of the rocky planets.

So they decide they want to build a second gas giant. The existing planet has more than enough mass to create 2 separate wells, if you could transport half it's mass to the other side of it's orbit.

The issue is though: How to transport the gas and keep it at the destination until it has enough mass to stay together through gravity?

- There is a dyson sphere so energy is not a issue
- It's perfectly fine if this project takes millenia. People are patient.
- I'm flexible in terms of other things that might be present in this solar system, as long as there is only 1 gas giant.
- Transporting significant mass via FTL is not feasable

Answer (score 4):

To set a starting point, Earth loses about 95000 tons of hydrogen per year, due to thermal escape. And Earth doesn't have enough mass to keep hydrogen in its gravity well.

If you have a starting mass similar to that of Earth, which can act as docking point and you are able to bring more than 95000 tons of hydrogen per year, you end up with a net positive balance. For comparison, a TI class supertanker can carry 440000 tons of oil.

And here is the trick: to increase the trapping of the matter you can carrying, you can either cool it down (lower thermal energy = lower escape rate) or convert it to hydrocarbons so that they take longer to decompose and gassify.

Then you have just to set a route of space equivalent of tankers to keep plumping up the docking planet.